# Calling method on parent form from child form

Tags: c#, methods

I’ve been trying to get this to work for a while but can’t (I am fairly new to C# and OOP in general).

Basically, I have this piece of code on a second form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (charCount > 2 && charCount < 30)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        //Error handling code here
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        //Run the SQL statements
        try
        {

        //SQL insert data is here

        }
        catch (Exception ie)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ie.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            //Close the connection
            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

            mainForm.refreshCall();

            this.Close();
        }

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Part numbers can be between 2 and 30 characters.\n Yours was " + charCount + " characters long.", "Error");
    }

}
```

It all runs fine and does what it’s supposed to, which is insert some data into a SQL database (I took that code out to make it a little cleaner). So after all that happens, I try to execute `mainForm.refreshCall()`. This refreshCall method exists on my first form, or `mainForm`, and looks like this:

```
public static void refreshCall()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DSERVER\\NEW_SQL;Initial Catalog=AWSoftware;Integrated Security=True");
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT part_num from dbo.CustomParts", conn);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        this.listParts.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        this.listParts.DisplayMember = "part_num";
        conn.Close();
    }

    catch (SqlException odbcEx)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There was an error connecting to the data source\nError Code: 1001", "Database Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

However, `this.listParts.DataSource` and `this.listParts.DisplayMember` both tell me that they are not valid static properties Error, static method, or static field initialize. I am absolutely baffled by what that means. If someone would be so kind as to shed some light on this for me, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `refreshCall` is marked as `static`, but you are referencing instantiated variables, in this case, your `ListBox`, so that won't work.  You either have to pass in the ListBox as a parameter reference, or just remove the `static` attribute.

Simplest way:

```
public void refreshCall() {
  // blah-blah
}
```

then the method call changes to:

```
this.refreshCall();
```

Comment: When I change the call to this.RefreshCall() I get "Program.addPart' does not contain a definition for 'refreshCall' and no extension method 'refreshCall' accepting a first argument of type 'Program.addPart' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: @AndrewDeForest `this.refreshCall()` only works from within the `MainForm` form, since that is what `this` is referring to.  If another form in your program is trying to make that call, it would need to have the reference to the MainForm you are using, for example, myForm, in which case, it would be `myForm.refreshCall()`.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, this does make sense, in fact it is originally what I tried doing, but then I get a message saying "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property".